# Don't want to tap in same position

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, touch

Xna wp7 game.

At the moment, this piece of code, lets me spawn ball everytime I tap.

What I want is, not let the user tap in the same position. i.e. force him not to spam in the same position.

```
foreach (TouchLocation location in TouchPanel.GetState())
{
    TouchLocation prevLocation;
    bool prevLocationAvailable = location.TryGetPreviousLocation(out prevLocation);

    if (location.State == TouchLocationState.Moved && prevLocation.State != TouchLocationState.Moved)
    {
        if (hitbox.Contains((int)location.Position.X, (int)location.Position.Y))
          releaseBalls();
    }
 }
```

Hitbox is a rectangle which is defined as being the whole screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. I have made a small rectangle with my touch positions. Then I checked if it hits my new rectangle. If not, spawn a ball. :D

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use your collision detection to do this for you?

Given that you have the position of previous tap (ball) and position of the new tap you can calculate if the two balls overlap (the distance between their centers is less than ball diameter) and even compensate for overlap if you wanted to by moving the ball to a valid position right next to the previous ball.

You are probably keeping track of all ball positions already so you can extend the above logic to compare the about to be spawned ball position to all balls already within your Hitbox rectangle and make sure they don't overlap.

My 2 cents :)